# htaccess redirect HTTPS to secure.domain.com, non https to www.domain.com

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Not sure how to best write the following rules:

1. All secure (HTTPS) traffic should redirect to https://secure.domain.com
2. Non-secure requests to secure.domain.com should redirect to https://secure.domain.com
3. All other non-secure requests should go to http://www.domain.com
4. Lastly, all non-www requests should redirect to www, except the "secure" subdomain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the following to your htaccess file in the root folder of your domain.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /


#Non-secure requests to secure.domain.com should redirect to https://secure.domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^secure\.domain\.com$ [NC]  
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301] 

#All secure (HTTPS) traffic should redirect to https://secure.domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^secure\.domain\.com$ [NC]  
RewriteRule .* https://secure.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301] 


#All other non-secure requests should go to http://www.domain.com
#Lastly, all non-www requests should redirect to www, except the "secure" subdomain.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]  
RewriteRule .* http://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Outstanding, worked like a charm! I knew I was over-thinking it.