# Rewrite unsecured subdomain to secured

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

I know this has been answered, as in this post [htaccess redirect HTTPS to secure.domain.com, non https to www.domain.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809835/htaccess-redirect-https-to-secure-domain-com-non-https-to-www-domain-com)

but I just can't get this to work. I have two ip addresses. One points at the main domain, domain.com that is not secured. The second points at the subdomain.domain.com which is secured. What I need is for subdomain.domain.com to be rewritten to https://subdomain.domain.com. If anyone has any more information that could help with this I would be so very thankful. This is the .htaccess code I am currently using with no success-

```
#Non-secure requests to subdomain.domain.com should redirect to https://secure.domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Downvote with no comment? thanks.... so very very helpful...

Comment: Redirect to `https://subdomain.domain.com` or to `https://secure.domain.com` ???

Answer (score 0):

Did you turn on RewriteEngine?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
```

make sure these two lines are above the line in your post.